# MYSQL 'Incorrect file format' and 'is not a MyISAM-table'

Tags: mysql

Try to repair table using `REPAIR TABLE tablename;` and i get this error message.

> Incorrect file format 'tablename'

Try to repair using `myisamchk.exe -s -f -U -auto-repair C:\xampp\mysql\data\databasename\*.MYI`

> myisamchk: error: 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\databasename\tablename.MYI' is not a MyISAM-table

3 files found under the database folder .frm .MYD .MYI

Always display in use in phpmyadmin

[image]

Comment: The table body file is damaged till non-recoverability. Restore it from backup.

Comment: How big is the table?  Did the issue occur _before_ running myisamchk?  Was there a recent crash?  (I don't see an obvious answer; I am hoping more details of the timeline will help.)